# "didnt have the phone to myself yesterday" it it correct?

Tags: expressions, questions

> "I didn't have the phone to myself yesterday"

Is that a correct sentence and a way of telling someone that your phone was not with you yesterday and that is why you couldn't reply

Answer (score 4):

To have something "to yourself" means to have it for your exclusive use.

> "I did not have the beach to myself - there were several other people
>   on it".

The example sentence you give means that you were sharing your phone with other people.

It is normal and correct to say

> I did not have my phone with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think "I did not have the phone with me yesterday " is very simple and grammatical.

I did not have the phone to myself sounds ungrammatical and odd to me

Comment: @Fumble Fingers. I would like to know whether" I did not have the phone with me yesterday " is Right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not necessarily wrong. In the days when people did not carry telephones around with them all the time, it was quite common for a single phone to be shared by numerous people. In those circumstances, it would be a very reasonable explanation of not being able to receive  a call (possibly of a very private nature) that one 'did not have the phone to [oneself]'.

If the sentence referred to a time in the 1950s, say, it would be fine (if the intended meaning was as I have indicated).